# jquery not listening to data element after interaction

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I wasn't sure the best title for this one...

[Live Link Provided Here](http://dev.schlagelassociates.com/News/Publications)

My overall goal for this project.  There are certain documents that require an email be required to download them.  Through asp.net I am binding a repeater and then with jquery removing the href and placing it in the rel tag until they add their email address.

```
$('a[data-email="True"]').each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', '#_');
    $(this).attr('rel', href);
});
```

The jquery checks to see if the `data-email` tag = "True" if it is then the `bootstrap modal` will pop up and via `ajax` the form calls a `web method` and adds the email to the database if it isn't a duplicate.

```
$('.emailcheck').live("click", function (e) {        
    if ($(this).data("email") == "True") {
        $('#emailModal').modal();
    }
});
```

Upon success the modal will close and on each `data-email="True"` the link is added back to the `href` and the `data-email` is set to False

```
$('#emailModal').modal('hide');
$('body a[data-email="True"]').each(function () {
    var reltag = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(this).attr('href', reltag);
    $(this).attr('data-email', 'False');
});
```

All of this happens successfully, and the email downloads upon another click. However, when I click the download link the modal still pops up.

Can someone please guide me to a solution as to why the modal is still popping up.  Also in the success script is there a way to automatically trigger the download?

Comment: May be you can use `$(this).removeAttr('data-email');` instead of `$(this).attr('data-email', 'False');`, so it'll remove the `data-attr`.

Comment: I dont see the code to initiate the modal. I assume there is a click event attached to the anchors to pop the modal if data-email = true. Need to put an else if false to not pop modal.

Comment: @Sheikh Heera Good thought, same outcome though.  Somehow it seems to still read what was originally loaded in the DOM

Comment: @Syon I've edited the question to include that code. You can also view the live page a http://dev.schlagelassociates.com/News/Publications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - not much of a change but here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jKmKZ/) showing it should work

**OnLoad Function**

```
$('.emailcheck').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', '#_').attr('rel', href);
});
```

**Click Event**

```
$(document).on("click", '.emailcheck', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if ($(this).attr("data-email") == "True") {
        $('#emailModal').modal();
    }
});
```

**Email Submit Function**

```
$('#emailModal').modal('hide');
$('.emailcheck').each(function() {
    var reltag = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(this).attr('href', reltag).attr('data-email', 'False');
});
```

Comment: Only thing I had to change was removing the e.preventDefault() on the click event.  Because after it put the href back in place it wouldn't download otherwise. Bonus: any tips to automatically trigger the download without a second click?

Comment: Ahh cool. The only thing that comes to mind is to set `document.location.href = reltag;` but that will take them off the page - I don't think it will trigger the download. Never tried before though.

Comment: Can you set the target on that call?

Comment: No, but you could try: window.open(reltag,'Download');